# Dell Latitude 3540 A14 BIOS laptop: No bootable device

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, dell-latitude, dell

Attempting to install/upgrade my HDD in my Latitude 3540 to a Western Digital 1TB with a clean install. Using a 32GB flash drive and Rufus to clean the new HDD.

I am not completely ignorant when it comes to tech, but I am also not an experienced individual when it comes to all of the technical aspects. I am learning a lot as I go.

I do not believe it has any OS on it currently. Was running Windows 10 Pro on it. Do I need to re-install Windows 10 or the original OS?

Comment: Thats not making sense.  What did it have before?  Does that still exist on the Drive? What do want on the drive?

Comment: Before the attempt at putting in the 1TB HDD, it was running Windows 10 Pro. When I followed the prompts to install Windows 10 to the new HDD through SATA TO USB cable, it completely wiped my original HDD. I have formatted both HDDs to NTFS and exFAT and retried clean install from USB with no success. I want to put Windows 10 Pro on the new 1TB HDD

Comment: *I want to put Windows 10 Pro on the new 1TB HDD* So install it as usual. Just make sure the drive is GPT then let the installer create all the required partitions. Do NOT do it yourself unless you know exactly the result you want.